# MIT app inventor

Tags: android

I am using the MIT app inventor to develop a mobile app. I can't extend the scope (more than 300 items) of the list.

[image: [1]]
 It cannot be given the option me to extend the app.

If I change it to near to 298 items, it does not give me a chance to extend it. If I select the "more option" it display the *warning unresponsive script* dialog box. If I choose to continue it nothing happens.

I searched the internet and StackOverflow, but I haven't found any good answer to this.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options :

1) use other app inventor forks on pc

2) by external source

- create an empty list
- load your list items externally like in csv format, this can be done by downloading the resources upon first use or button click (see the pura vida website on how to download). the resource will be downloaded in the default download folder
- set your list elements to the elements of the data source. for path, set it to path-of-download-folder/myfile.extention

this approach will also prevent you from being bored with manually trying to enter data